# Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined: Vue Dynamic import, Lazy loading

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js

I am getting following error. There are many other 'visually' similar questions out there. But I am not able to figure out those. I am using webpack. This template is generated from microsoft's javascriptservices templates. I have modified them to make them work with dynamic templates import.

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

vendor.js?v=MxNIG8b0Wz6QtAfWhyA0-4CCwZshMscBGmtIBXxKshw:13856     

found in 

---> <MenuComponent>
       <T> at ClientApp\components\app\app.vue.html
         <Root>
warn @ vendor.js?v=MxNIG8b0Wz6QtAfWhyA0-4CCwZshMscBGmtIBXxKshw:13856
```

My boot.ts looks like below.

```
import './css/site.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const Counter = () => import('./components/counter/counter');

const routes = [
    { path: '/', component:  require('./components/home/home.vue.html').default },
    { path: '/counter', component: Counter }
];

new Vue({
    el: '#app-root',
    router: new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes }),
    render: h => h(require('./components/app/app.vue.html').default)
});
```

My app.vue.html is as below:

```
<template>
    <div id='app-root' class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <menu-component />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <router-view></router-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="./app.ts"></script>
```

My app.ts is as below:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component({
    components: {
        MenuComponent: require('../navmenu/navmenu.vue.html')
    }
})
export default class AppComponent extends Vue {
}
```

[UPDATED]
Guys. Now I got this resolved with following change.

One place was missing **.default** after **require**. and that was in boot.ts

also instead of below:

```
import('./components/counter/counter')
```

I had to write below:

```
import('./components/counter/counter').then(m => m.default)
```

**Now QUESTION is why it is an issue?** 
I have 
"vue": "^2.5.16", 
"vue-loader": "^14.2.2", 
"vue-router": "^3.0.1".

Whereas following link says with these versions, these **default** related changes are not required, if I am not wrong.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/releases/tag/v13.0.0

Comment: The `.default` property happen because when you do `export default something`, that something becomes available in the `import('module').default`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> instead of below:
>
> ```
> import('./components/counter/counter')
> ```
>
> I had to write below:
>
> ```
> import('./components/counter/counter').then(m => m.default)
> ```
>
> **Now QUESTION is why it is an issue?**
>
> I have
>
> - "vue": "^2.5.16",
> - "vue-loader": "^14.2.2",
> - "vue-router": "^3.0.1".

These `.default` due to `esModule` option being `true` in the new versions.

You can either use the `.default` or you can turn off the new behavior by explicitly using `esModule: false` in `vue-loader` options.

Example:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          },
          esModule: false // example of setting to false
        }
      },
```

Comment: These can be configured from webpack. So, it works with vue.html files as well. Issue is with dynamic import.

Comment: Yes, it can be configured. You didn't mention it, good to know you configured it. I have updated the answer. Now I talk about the `default` thing.

Comment: Have added example on how to set `esModule` to `false`.